# Select columns that have same values

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm a bit lost with a request, here is my table schema

id PK
tickets_id
type

lets say i have these rows

```
id     tickets_id      type
75        55            1
76        55            2 
77        56            1
78        56            2
79        56            3 
80        58            1
81        59            1
82        59            2
```

What I need is to list all tickets_id that doesn't have a type '2' in another row but only 1 or 3

So here it would only list tickets_id 58

Not asking for full solution, just a little track, I don't know how to start :/

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Thanks for the edit Metal, you were faster than me :D

Comment: Specify the expected result-set as well. (Do you want a single column/row, or all matching rows, with all columns etc.)

Answer (score 1):

use not exists

```
    select t1.* from table_name t1
    where not exists ( select 1 from table_name t2 where t1.tickets_id=t2.tickets_id
                        and type=2
                     )
```

Answer (score 1):

You could simply use MySQL [`NOT IN`](https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/comparision-functions-and-operators/not-in.php) function:

```
SELECT DISTINCT tickets_id
FROM t
WHERE tickets_id NOT IN (
  SELECT tickets_id
  FROM t
  WHERE type = 2
)
```

Comment: Note that NOT IN is a bit tricky if null values are involved.

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume that your table's name is tickets

```
SELECT * 
FROM tickets 
WHERE tickets_id NOT IN (
SELECT tickets_id FROM tickets 
WHERE type=2
)
```

Comment: Note that NOT IN is a bit tricky if null values are involved.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want `ticket_id`, then use aggregation:

```
select tickets_id
from t
group by tickets_id
having sum( type = 2 ) = 0;  -- no type 2s
```

Presumably, the rest of the values are 1s and 3s.  If you want to add this condition explicitly, then use:

```
select tickets_id
from t
where type in (1, 2, 3)
group by tickets_id
having sum( type = 2 ) = 0;  -- no type 2s
```

If you wanted *all* ticket ids, even those not in those tables, then I would assume you have another table with one row per `tickets_id`.  In this case, I would recommend `not exists`:

```
select ts.*
from tickets ts
where not exists (select 1
                  from t
                  where t.tickets_id = ts.tickets_id and t.type = 2
                 );
```